# Javascript event callback to PowerBuilder with data

Tags: javascript, powerbuilder, ole

I am using PowerBuilder 2017 and have created an OLE control (Microsoft Web Browser) with a local html file using Leaflet JS.

When a user clicks on a marker on the leaflet map I would like a reference value (coordinates) sent back to PowerBuilder where the code there can react to the user event.

My question is how can I get a javascript event to also trigger an event in the  main PowerBuilder application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigating I have managed to solve my problem, I added the following code into PowerBuilder, inside the OLE Control's click event:

```
oleobject lole_data
string ls_innertext, ls_classname

lole_data = This.Object.Document.ActiveElement

if not IsNull(lole_data) then

    ls_classname = Lower( string(This.Object.Document.ActiveElement.classname)) 
    if ls_classname = "leaflet-popup-content" then  
        ls_innertext = string(lole_data.parentNode.InnerText)
    end if  

end if
```

ActiveElement is the method to use.  I obtain the Leaflet class and can identify it is in fact a Marker PopUp that was clicked.